# Enforce user compliance on SharePoint 2013 survey

Tags: 2013, survey

How can one deploy a SharePoint 2013 survey that

- Automatically start at user login, if the user has not completed the survey
- Ensure survey cannot be Closed or Cancel
- Disables other windows on user's desktop thereby preventing the user from ignoring the survey
  Thanks

N/B: not best practice, but there is a specific requirement for this